# Resizing TextView

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

In my iphone app I have a TextField to enter a name and a TextView to enter a description. In my viewDidLoad method I am making the TextView bigger if the display is 4" for iPhone 5.

```
if (IS_IPHONE_5) {
        CGRect frameRect = self.eventDetails.frame;
        frameRect.size.height = 160;
        self.eventDetails.frame = frameRect;
}
```

This works fine when the view loads, but if I enter on the TextField first and then touch the TextView, the TextView shrinks to its original size.  If I enter on the TextView first it does not shrink, only if I go into the TextField and then on to the TextView.  Is there any way I can keep the height at 160?

Thanks,
Kev.

Comment: anywhere else you are changing its height?

Comment: in that condition. try to add size of textField programmatically .

Comment: This is the only place I am changing its height.  When first responder is resigned from the textField the textView shrinks to its size in Interface Builder.  Something must happen after resignFirstResponder?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding autoResizingMask which automatically changes when view bounds changes for example orientation.

```
[self.eventDetails setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];
```

other values:
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleRightMargin
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight
UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin

Comment: Nope, no joy still not working.  Would love to know what is happening to the view when the first responder is resigned.

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer from the iOS dev forums.

viewDidLoad method should not be used to set frames.  Try moving your code to the viewDidLayoutSubviews method.